# /system/bin/sh: cat:duty_pcts:I/O error

Tags: linux, unix

There are some question with linux command **cat**

```
#cd /sys/class/leds/green
# ls -al
....
-rw-rw-r-- root    root   4096  1970-01-02 08:00 duty_pcts
....
#cat duty_pctys
```

the error occur at this time

```
__/system/bin/sh: cat:duty_pcts:I/O error__
```

Comment: Suggest you to post the output from the /var/log/messages file. This may provide us more insight.

Comment: @kumar_m_kiran  I'm sorry. This was not an real linux or unix system .It's base on Android Phone!

Answer (score 0):

The `cat` command tells you "Hey, I've tried to read that file named duty_pcts, but for some reason the read failed. I asked the OS for the error code in the `errno` variable and the OS told me it was an I/O error (EIO)."

Read the manual pages for errno, open(2), read(2) and close(2) [e.g. with `man 2 read`] and look if any of the system calls can set `errno` to `EIO`. For `read(2)` you will find for example,

> ```
>    EIO    I/O error. This will happen for example when the process is in
>           a background process group, tries to read from its controlling
>           tty, and either it is ignoring or blocking SIGTTIN or its pro-
>           cess group is orphaned.  It may also occur  when  there  is  a
>           low-level I/O error while reading from a disk or tape.
> ```